# Protect url from getting intercepted

Tags: html, security, url

I am currently trying to set up a form. clients need to fill out certain information and based on the information, they will be redirected to another page. While redirecting, certain information such as their name will be carried by the url. What is the risk of url getting intercepted and how can i protect this data while in transit?

When I set up the forms, i saw that information such as names are visible on the url,a nd this is something that I do not want.

Comment: is it all https? The values will all be visible on the client browser that receives them, but the URL path is part of the encrypted data in the HTTPS protocol. Just not the IP address or domain (unless using encrypted DNS)